# @-moz-document url-prefix() not working

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage and a CSS file for it.My problem is in the CSS file when I am using

@-moz-document url-prefix()

On my computer the CSS rules apply but on anothe computer it does not work(tested with same version of Firefox) which is really odd.
Here is my exact CSS code if that helps in any way:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
{

  .SelectStyle {
    position:relative;
    top:-17px;
  }

}

.SelectStyle {
float:right;
}
```

Am I missing or doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

**2018: Firefox support for @-moz-document url-prefix() is being removed** 
Just in case someone will watch this, firefoz remove the support for @-moz-document url-prefix() in 28 May 2018.

Instead you can use one of the following syntax:

```css
@media screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   .selector {
      property: value;
   }
 }

_:-moz-tree-row(hover), .selector{
     property: value;
}
```

Comment: when I search for `min--moz-device-pixel-ratio` or `-moz-tree-row`, they both come with scary MDN warnings about how they are non-standard and unsupported.